# Best performance method for getting records by large collection of IDs

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a query with code to select all records from a table where a column value is contained in a CSV.  I found a suggestion that the best way to do this was using ARRAY functionality in PostgresQL.

I have a table `price_mapping` and it has a primary key of `id` and a column `customer_id` of type `bigint`.

I want to return all records that have a customer ID in the array I will generate from csv.

I tried this:

```
select * from price_mapping
where ARRAY[customer_id] <@ ARRAY[5,7,10]::bigint[]
```

(the 5,7,10 part would actually be a csv inserted by my app)

But I am not sure that is right.  In application the array could contain 10's of thousands of IDs so want to make sure I am doing right with best performance method.

Is this the right way in PostgreSQL to retrieve large collection of records by pre-defined column value?

Thanks

Comment: Generally this is done via `where customer_id in (5, 7, 10)`. Otherwise, the best performance would be to not search for tens of thousands of IDs. I assume they're not randomly chosen. Is there anything which relates those IDs together?

Comment: I have this list in memory from a previous step in the process (it will vary).  The data could also be got by making several table joins but i figured that would be slower.  So performance on `IN` would be better than using array?

Comment: Several table joins might be much faster, relational databases are good at relations. And perhaps you need to redesign your steps. Ask about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is done with the SQL standard [`in` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_in.asp).

```
select *
from price_mapping
where customer_id in (5,7,10)
```

I don't see any reason using `ARRAY` would be faster. [It might be slower given it has to build arrays](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/), though it might have been optimized.

In the past this was more optimal:

```
select *
from price_mapping
where customer_id = ANY(VALUES (5), (7), (10)
```

But new-ish versions of Postgres should optimize this for you.

Passing in tens of thousands of IDs might run up against a query size limit either in Postgres or your database driver, so you may wish to batch this a few thousand at a time.

---

As for the best performance, the answer is to not search for tens of thousands of IDs. Find *something* which relates them together, index that column, and search by that.

Comment: "*I don't see any reason using ARRAY would be faster*" actually `customer_id in (5,7,10)` gets rewritten to `customer_id = any(ARRAY[5,7,10])` by the query optimizer

Answer (score 1):

If your data is big enough, try this:

- Read your CSV using a FDW ([foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html))
- If you need this connection often, you might build a materialized view from it, holding only needed columns. Refresh this when new CSV is created.
- Join your table against this foreign table or materialized viev.